# Mapping Arrays in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array A

```
Array([0]=>5 [1]=>12)
```

and array B

```
Array([0]=>red [1]=>green)
```

I must make a new array C

```
Array([5]=>red [12]=>green)
```

i.e. the first value of A must will be the key for the 1st value of B.

How this can be done in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this?

```
array_combine($array1,$array2)
```

Its PHP function designed for that porpose..
 [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) for more.

Comment: There can't be a better answer than this one for this question

Answer (score 0):

how about pure php

```
$c = array()
$limit = count($a);

for($i=0 ; $i<$limit ; $i++)
{
    $c[ $a[$i] ] = $b[$i];
}
```

Comment: You should avoid putting the count in the for loop, as it will run that function for every iteration.